# Using NAudio with UDP and no microphone

Tags: c#, udp, wav, naudio, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to receive UDP data on a specified IP address and port, and convert it into a WAV file using C# and VS 2017. I did some Google’ing and read that NAudio can help do this. So I downloaded the NAudioDemo on https://github.com/naudio/NAudio, and opened the NAudioDemo project in VS 2017. After ensuring the NAudio NuGet package was restored I ran the project, selected the Network Chat demo to load and clicked the Load button.

This loaded the Network Chat demo.
I entered the correct IP Address and Port number in the text boxes, and made sure the Compression and Protocol values were set correctly.

[image: NAudio Demo (x64) screen shot]

You will notice in the screen shot the Input Device drop down hasn’t been set. This is because I’m running the demo on **Windows Server 2012 R2**, and the server doesn’t have any input devices setup and there is nothing in the drop down to select.

When I click the Start Streaming button it calls the `NetworkChatPanel.Connect` method, and this instantiates a new `NetworkAudioPlayer` object. Inside the constructor of the `NetworkAudioPlayer` class it runs the following code:

```
public NetworkAudioPlayer(INetworkChatCodec codec, IAudioReceiver receiver)
{
    this.codec = codec;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    receiver.OnReceived(OnDataReceived);

    waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(codec.RecordFormat);
    waveOut.Init(waveProvider);
    waveOut.Play();
}
```

It creates a new `WaveOut` object instance and calls the `waveOut.Init` method. This causes the following exception to be thrown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'NAudio.MmException' occurred in
>   NAudio.dll BadDeviceId calling waveOutOpen occurred

I’m wondering if the exception was thrown because the server I’m running on has no input device(s). Or it could be something else.

Can you please help me get this running and working on Windows Server 2012 R2 with no input device(s), so I can save the UDP data as a WAV file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously with no soundcard you can't play audio. So get rid of all code relating to `WaveOut`, and create a `WaveFileWriter` instead. When you get a `DataReceived` event, write the received audio into the `WaveFileWriter` (with the `Write` method). Then make sure to `Dispose` the `WaveFileWriter` when you're done